# MPMediaItem - NSCoding problem with MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

So MPMediaItem conforms to NSCoding, but it contains a pointer to MPMediaItemArtwork, which doesn't conform to NSCoding. So if I try to archive a MPMediaItem, if that item has some artwork in it, it will not be able to unarchive.

I tried to make a category of MPMediaItemArtwork and make it conform to NSCoding, but I can't seem to do that because we don't have access to the actual UIImage that it stores. Does anyone know of any other creative ways to get around this problem? I want to be able to archive an MPMediaItem, even if it means somehow stripping off the artwork object. Is there a way to make a category of a class to strip away certain functionality (instead of just adding more, like we do with categories)? Or any other clever way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug report with Apple on this.  Personally, I would think if a class is said to conform to NSCoding, it needs to be able to actually Encode all composite properties correctly.

At the very least, MPMediaItem should not encode anything about the MPMediaItemArtwork and instead, recreate it when unarchived.

Comment: Filed a bug report. Hopefully there's some way this can be done before the bug is fixed in 4.0.

Comment: did anything ever happen with this?  did you file a bug?

Comment: I'm wondering what the latest is with this one.

Comment: 7 years on, and I came looking for an answer for the same problem!

Comment: I abandoned my project back then so I haven't kept track, but I also never got a response to the original bug report, and it doesn't look like anything's changed since then.