# NSKeyedUnarchiver not working after received NSData from other Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, networking

I'm trying to send an array with the iOS MultipeerConnectivityKit.
I sent the array using

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:inArray];
[multipeerManager sendDataReliable:data toPeers:[multipeerManager.session connectedPeers];
```

and receiving on another device with:

```
   - (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
     {
     NSArray *receivedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:inData]];
     NSLog(@"%@",receivedArray); // returns (   )
     }
```

when I run the code on the same device (archiving und unarchiving) the arrays gets unarchived properly, but after I received the NSData (which is exactly the same if I do an NSLog() on both devices) and put them in NSKeyedUnarchiver on another device, the received array is empty. Nothing crashes, the array is simply empty.

The Array has 3 Objects, two NSStrings and a MPMediaItemArtwork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are doing the testing the right way - this shouldn't work even on the original device.

`MPMediaItemArtwork` does not conform to `NSCoding` protocol.

There was a [related unsolved problem here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2444870/653513) 3 years ago.

I guess solution to this would be using this [MPConcreteMediaItemArtwork](https://github.com/Musixmatchdev/ObjectiveHeaders/tree/master/Headers/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/MediaPlayer) which implements the protocol needed.

Comment: Yes! I used an UIImage instead of the MPMediaItemArtwork. Thank you, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
     {
     NSArray *receivedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:inData]];
     NSLog(@"%@",receivedArray); // returns (   )
     }
```

The method,

```
unarchiveObjectWithData
```

returns id, could you please cast to an `NSArray`before you pass it to,

```
initWithArray
```

method.